# R f\Functions/Macros and Generating Calls From Data

Tags: r, macros, sas

So I'm a proficient SAS user but very new to R. I am finding myself frustrated because I cannot figure out how to do something in R that's pretty simple in SAS, and so I assume simple in R. I think there's something that I'm missing at a very fundamental level about the way R works.

In R, I am using the airquality dataset and trying to do a scatter plot of every variable by every variable.

In SAS I would do something like the following:

```
proc contents data=airquality noprint out=contents;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  create table all_combs as select A.name,B.name as name2 from contents A, contents B where a.name ne B.name;
  select cats('%scatter(',name,',',name2,')') into :scatter separated by ' ' from all_combs;
quit;

%macro scatter(x,y);
  proc sqplot data=airquality;
  scatter x=&x. y=&y.;
  run;
%mend;

&scatter.;
```

The basic process is to generate a list of variables from the data and generate the cartesian product. The result is thrown into a series of macro calls that are stored in a macro variable which is called after you define the macro.

I assume the way to do this in R is to generate a function to do this, but I failed there. I expected the below to work and it didn't and I don't understand why.

```
plotfun=function(v1,v2){plotfun=plot(airquality$v1,airquality$v2)}
plotfun(Wind,Temp)
```

Even after I do that part I don't know how to automatically generate the calls of the function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `plot(airquality)` will give you a scatterplot of all variables in a grid. The glory of R is that `plot` guesses, often quite well, what sort of things you would want to plot based on the object you are plotting.

Comment: You can't use the "$" syntax followed by variables. You would need to do `airquality[,v1]`

Answer (score 2):

This might do what you were hoping:

```
plotfun=function(df, v1,v2){ plot(df[[v1]],df[[v2]]) }
plotfun(airquality, 'Wind','Temp')
```

Note that your code would have caused the R interpreter to go looking for a variable named 'Wind', then passed it to v1 but it would have failed even if it had found such a variable, since `$` does not evaluate its second argument, `v1` in your case.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. So next I tried the code I'm posting below, but it still doesn't get me there...                plotfun=function(df, v1,v2){ plot(df[[v1]],df[[v2]]) }
list=ls(airquality)
for (i in 1 to 5){
    plotfun(airquality,list[i],list[i+1])
}                                                                         I expected that it would resolve list[i] and list[i+1] and pop in the name of the column that is being held in 'list' but it doesn't seem to do that. Apparently lists aren't like SAS macro variables which hold text.

Comment: The error I got says that the interpreter choked on the `for(i in 1 to 5)` part. The assignment to the variable `list` succeeded. There is no `to` in R `for` sequences. Using the variable 'list' is a really bad idea because it will confuse you and everyone else who reads your code. Changing it to `for(i in 1:5){...}` succeeded. My observation is that people too often fail to actually read what the error messages say, and instead make up incorrect theories.

Comment: You're right on the error stuff, my bad. I know I've said similar things about people with SAS errors. I'm brand new to R and I do want to learn it, so I hope you can give me a pass. ;)

Comment: How would you accomplish what I'm trying to do? Certainly in SAS I wouldn't do it in a do loop (as I didn't in my above example). More what I'm trying to learn how to do is to program in a data driven fashion as I typically do in SAS. Basically in my SAS code I generate a data set with the cartesian product of the variable names and then generate macro calls (equivalent to the function calls I'm doing in R) from that data set which are stored in a macro variable. Would a similar process in R be understandable to the typical programmer? If so, I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: If I want to do what you originally described I would execute two lines of code: `require(lattice); splom( ~ airquality[1:6] , airquality)` . I can't really tell if that meets your expectations. The two functions `expand.grid` and `combn` are very useful in forming two different versions of what I think you might mean by the "Cartesian product".